Create a new column for each value in another column
I would like to transform table like this:



Fixed
Part
Original column




U
1
b


U
1
c


U
1
d


X
4
e


Y
5
f


Z
6
g


Z
6
h


W
8
i



to table like this:



Fixed
Part
New column 1
New column 2
New column 3




U
1
b
c
d


X
4
e




Y
5
f




Z
6
g
h



W
8
i





Number of Fixed Part columns is >= 2.
Number of the new columns (different values in Original column for unique value in Fixed Part columns) is not known.
It would be nice to do it in Excel, but TSQL or PowerBI will do the job.
I tried to find an answer on Google and Copilot without luck.

What have you tried so far? Can you give code examples.

You can do this in Excel via Power Query (same as Power BI).
In Excel, select the table, then select From Table/Range in the Data tab in the ribbon. This will open the Power Query Editor.
Select Advanced Editor in the Home tab, and paste the following:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Fixed", type text}, {"Part", Int64.Type}, {"Original column", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Fixed"}, {{"Rows", each _, type table [Fixed=nullable text, Part=nullable number, Original column=nullable text]}}),
    AddColumnNames = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {"Rows", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "ColumnName", 1, 1)}),
    #"Expanded Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(AddColumnNames, "Rows", {"Part", "Original column", "ColumnName"}, {"Part", "Original column", "ColumnName"}),
    #"Added Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Rows", {{"ColumnName", each "New column " & Text.From(_, "en-GB"), type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Prefix", List.Distinct(#"Added Prefix"[ColumnName]), "ColumnName", "Original column")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"

And then select Done.
You should see the desired transformation. Then select Close & Load in the Home tab, and the new transformed table will appear in a new sheet.


Dear @Sam-Nseir, thank you very much for your response,
When I paste you formula and hit "Done" I get:
Expression.Error: 5 arguments were passed to function which expects between 2 and 4.
Details:
Pattern=
Arguments=List

Which version of Excel are you using? I've updated the answer above, give it another try.

With this formula in F2, this is the created table:
Uses BYROW, UNIQUE, TEXTSPLIT and TEXTJOIN functions
=LET(uni,BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:B9),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,x)))&"|",
tab,A2:A9&"|"&B2:B9&"|",
items,BYROW(uni,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,IF(x=tab,C2:C9,"")))),
IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",FALSE,uni&items),"|","#",TRUE),""))



Thank you very much @Black-cat for your response. When I paste the formula in F2 the table is correctly selected, but when I press Enter, I get an Invalid name (#NAME?) error. Could it be due to a local Excel configuration?
Best regards,

Generally #NAME error means that Excel cannot identify a function or name. In this case since this formula is a working one the problem can be that your Excel version not includes one of the functions or the language of Excel is not English.

One another alternative, if applicable could use of PIVOTBY():


=LET(
     a, "New Column "&MAP(A2:A9,B2:B9,LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS(x:A2,x,y:B2,y))),
     PIVOTBY(A2:B9,a,C2:C9,SINGLE,,0,,0))


Or, Using REDUCE():
=LET(
     a, A2:B9,
     b, UNIQUE(a),
     c, IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(b)),LAMBDA(x,y,
        VSTACK(x,TOROW(FILTER(C2:C9,(INDEX(b,y,1)=TAKE(a,,1))*(INDEX(b,y,2)=DROP(a,,1)),""))))),1),""),
     HSTACK(b,c))


